# How does the salmonmeter work? When do you get an emergency round?

Tags: splatoon-3

It's an argument between me and my SO:

When do you get a emergency round? When all players salmonmeter is full, or when one of the player's meter is full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance is based on the combined values of the meter in the top-right for each player, [referred to internally as the "team smell"](https://twitter.com/LeanYoshi/status/1578081235397664770).  The meter goes from values 0-5 and increases by 1 each game, and you only have a 100% chance of encountering Cohozuna if all team members have a full gauge.

If one player's meter is full, you have an absolute minimum chance of ~1.5%, but if you have stuck with the same team members for at least a few games, the chance should be somewhat greater than that.

[image: Team smell chance]